# How do I remove all spaces from a field in a Postgres database in an update query?

Tags: postgresql

What would be the proper syntax used to run an update query on a table to remove all spaces from the values in a column?

My table is called `users` and in the column `fullname` some values look like `'Adam Noel'`.  I want to remove the space so that the new value is `'AdamNoel'`

I have like 30k rows

Comment: Just do a search replace? Anything particular you find difficult?

Comment: I'd try
SELECT regexp_replace(myfield, ' ', '', 'g')
FROM mytable;

Comment: i did try it but the update amount of raw was more than what i what i have with space i mean space raw is 30k but the amount update was 45k , can we limite the update just for the space and ignore any other special charters – Marco DonJuan just now edit

Answer (score 92):

```
update users
  set fullname = replace(fullname, ' ', '');
```

Comment: i did try it but the update amount of raw was more than what i what i have with space i mean space raw is 30k  but the amount update was 45k ,  can we limite the update just for the space and ignore any other special charters

Comment: @MarcoDonJuan: sorry, you lost me at "space raw". I have no idea what you are talking about. Please create a sample at http://sqlfiddle.com and let us know how the new data should look like.

Comment: ok , ive fullname coulmn data like "Adam John" your statment removed space and its become "AdamJohn" which is pretty much what i want , but its also removed spiceal charters from other names like "mark'bart" "suzan_andy" etc

Comment: @LeoSam I tried `suzan_andy`  and `mark'bart`, `replace` didn't remove special characters. It works just fine!

Answer (score 26):

To remove all whitespace (not just space characters) one can use:

```
update users set fullname = regexp_replace(fullname, '\s', '', 'g');
commit;
```

Answer (score 13):

Just use the simple code

```
 REPLACE('some_string', ' ', '')
```

or

```
Replace('some_string', '\s', '')
```

to remove any white space from the string

Comment: `\s` has no special meaning for `replace()` the second statement removes a backslash followed by the character `s` from the string.

Comment: Sorry, but this answer is partly wrong and doesn't show anything, which has not already been shown in previous answers:
(1) There is no difference between `REPLACE()` and `Replace()`
(2) `REPLACE()` works, as you suggest, but this has already been shown in [2013 by user330315](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20376672/4742889).
(3) `REPLACE()` doesn't allow REGEX as you suggest by using `\s`

Answer (score 6):

You can include a condition to update only values that need it with the replace.

```
UPDATE users SET fullname = REPLACE(fullname, ' ', '') WHERE fullname ~* ' ';
```

Quick and dirty

Comment: Would that be the same as `UPDATE users SET fullname = REPLACE(fullname, ' ', '') WHERE fullname not like '% %';`

Comment: @jeremy : it should be `UPDATE users SET fullname = REPLACE(fullname, ' ', '') WHERE fullname like '% %';`

Answer (score 4):

If it's a `text[]` column, you can do something like this:

```
UPDATE users SET pets = string_to_array(replace(array_to_string(pets, ';'), ' ', ''), ';');
```

Before: `{"Big Dog", "Small Cat"}`

After: `{"BigDog", "SmallCat"}`

Answer (score 3):

Can perform an update all with the [`trim` function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-string.html).

```
UPDATE users AS u SET name = TRIM(u.name)
```

Optionally add a clause to update only the records that need it, instead of all, but uses more CPU.

```
UPDATE users AS u SET name = TRIM(u.name) WHERE LENGTH(TRIM(u.name)) <> LENGTH(u.name)
```

If the table has a unique index on the value being trimmed, you could get a duplicate key error.

Comment: PO wants to remove all white spaces, however, `trim` only remove space from start, end or both. Not remove space in the string.

Answer (score 1):

```
UPDATE customers SET first_name = TRIM (TRAILING FROM first_name ) where id = 1
```

For example, if you want to remove spaces from the beginning of a string, you use the following syntax:

TRIM(LEADING FROM string)
The following syntax of the TRIM() function removes all spaces from the end of a string.

TRIM(TRAILING FROM string)
And to remove all spaces at the beginning and ending of a string, you use the following syntax:

TRIM(BOTH FROM string)

Comment: It will not convert `Adam Noel` into `AdamNoel`