# How do I remove all spaces from of a lowercased field in a Postgres database in an select query?

Tags: java, postgresql, jpa, jpql

Hi I would like to know how I can Achieve this:
I want to remove blank spaces and lowercases  a field in a select statement  I tried from this question([How do I remove all spaces from a field in a Postgres database in an update query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20376579/how-do-i-remove-all-spaces-from-a-field-in-a-postgres-database-in-an-update-quer))   but I got a error.I am using EJB.

```
            String where = "";
            Map parametros = new HashMap();
            where += "( lower(replace(o.nombres, ' ', '')) like :nombres and   lower(replace(o.apellidos, ' ', '')) like :apellidos) ";
            parametros.put("nombres",  paciente.getNombres().toLowerCase().replaceAll("\\s+",""));
            parametros.put("apellidos", paciente.getApellidos().toLowerCase().replaceAll("\\s+",""));
            parametros.put(";whee", where);
            List<Pacientes> aux = ejbPaciente.encontarParametros(parametros);
```

**Error**

Error al ejecutar la consulta : class com.medkf.entidades.Pacientes java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: An exception occurred while creating a query in EntityManager: Exception Description: Syntax error parsing [Select object(o) from Pacientes as o where ( lower(replace(o.nombres, ' ', '')) like :nombres and lower(replace(o.apellidos, ' ', '')) like :apellidos) ]. [50, 77] The encapsulated expression is not a valid expression. [103, 132] The encapsulated expression is not a valid expression.

Thanks the help.

Comment: So what's the relationship between ejbPaciente, parametros and the where clause?

Comment: Hi,  parametros is  a hashmap from  which is built "select" clause(in the error) in ejbPacientes.encontrar(parametros)