# Create DB Constraint via Django

Tags: django, postgresql, check-constraints

I have a Django model which looks like this:

```
class Dummy(models.Model):
    ...
    system = models.CharField(max_length=16)
```

I want `system` never to be empty or to contain whitespace.

I know how to use validators in Django.

But I would enforce this at database level.

What is the easiest and django-like way to create a DB constraint for this?

I use PostgreSQL and don't need to support any other database.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**First issue:** creating a database constraint through Django

A)

<strike>It seems that django does not have this ability build in yet. There is a 9-year-old open [ticket](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/11964) for it, but I wouldn't hold my breath for something that has been going on this long.</strike>

Edit: As of release 2.2 (april 2019), Django supports database-level [check constraints](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/constraints/#django.db.models.CheckConstraint).

B) You could look into the package [django-db-constraints](https://github.com/rapilabs/django-db-constraints), through which you can define constraints in the model `Meta`. I did not test this package, so I don't know how useful it really is.

```py
# example using this package
class Meta:
    db_constraints = {
        'price_above_zero': 'check (price > 0)',
    }
```

---

**Second issue:** field `system` should never be empty nor contain whitespaces

Now we would need to build the `check` constraint in `postgres` syntax to accomplish that. I came up with these options:

1. Check if the length of `system` is different after removing whitespaces. Using ideas from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49038607/9225671) you could try:

   ```sql
   /* this check should only pass if `system` contains no
    * whitespaces (`\s` also detects new lines)
    */
   check ( length(system) = length(regexp_replace(system, '\s', '', 'g')) )
   ```
2. Check if the whitespace count is 0. For this you could us `regexp_matches`:

   ```sql
   /* this check should only pass if `system` contains no
    * whitespaces (`\s` also detects new lines)
    */
   check ( length(regexp_matches(system, '\s', 'g')) = 0 )
   ```

   Note that the `length` function **can't** be used with `regexp_matches` because the latter returns a `set of text[]` (set of arrays), but I could not find the proper function to count the elements of that set right now.

---

Finally, bringing **both of the previous issues** together, your approach could look like this:

```py
class Dummy(models.Model):
    # this already sets NOT NULL to the field in the database
    system = models.CharField(max_length=16)

    class Meta:
        db_constraints = {
            'system_no_spaces': 'check ( length(system) > 0 AND length(system) = length(regexp_replace(system, "\s", "", "g")) )',
        }
```

This checks that the fields value:

1. does not contain NULL (`CharField` adds `NOT NULL` constraint by default)
2. is not empty (first part of the `check`: `length(system) > 0`)
3. has no whitespaces (second part of the `check`: same length after replacing whitespace)

Let me know how that works out for you, or if there are problems or drawbacks to this approach.

Comment: Yes, your solution with the app django-db-constraints works. This is much better than writing migrations by hand with migrations.RunSQL(...).

Comment: That ticket is now fixed and the changes will be available, most likely, in Django 2.2.

Comment: Confirmed availability in 2.2: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/constraints/

Answer (score 29):

## 2019 Update

Django 2.2 added support for [database-level constrains](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/constraints/). The new [CheckConstraint](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/constraints/#django.db.models.CheckConstraint) and [UniqueConstraint](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/constraints/#django.db.models.UniqueConstraint) classes enable adding custom database constraints. Constraints are added to models using the [Meta.constraints option](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/options/#django.db.models.Options.constraints).

Your system validation would look like something like this:

```py
from django.db import models
from django.db.models.constraints import CheckConstraint
from django.db.models.query_utils import Q


class Dummy(models.Model):
    ...
    system = models.CharField(max_length=16)

    class Meta:
        constraints = [
            CheckConstraint(
                check=~Q(system="") & ~Q(system__contains=" "),
                name="system_not_blank")
        ]
```

Comment: This answer should be THE solution since it uses builtin' Django feature to achieve the desired goal.

Answer (score 9):

You can add `CHECK` constraint via custom django migration. To check string length you can use `char_length` function and `position` to check for containing whitespaces.

Quote from postgres docs (https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/ddl-constraints.html):

> A check constraint is the most generic constraint type. It allows you
>   to specify that the value in a certain column must satisfy a Boolean
>   (truth-value) expression.

To run arbitrary sql in migaration `RunSQL` operation can be used (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/migration-operations/#runsql):

> Allows running of arbitrary SQL on the database - useful for more
>   advanced features of database backends that Django doesn’t support
>   directly, like partial indexes.

**Create empty migration:**

```
python manage.py makemigrations --empty yourappname
```

**Add sql to create constraint:**

```
# Generated by Django A.B on YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM
from django.db import migrations

class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        ('yourappname', '0001_initial'),
    ]

    operations = [
         migrations.RunSQL('ALTER TABLE appname_dummy ADD CONSTRAINT syslen '
                           'CHECK (char_length(trim(system)) > 1);',
                           'ALTER TABLE appname_dummy DROP CONSTRAINT syslen;'),
         migrations.RunSQL('ALTER TABLE appname_dummy ADD CONSTRAINT syswh '
                           'CHECK (position(' ' in trim(system)) = 0);',
                           'ALTER TABLE appname_dummy DROP CONSTRAINT syswh;')


    ]
```

**Run migration:**

```
python manage.py migrate yourappname
```

Answer (score 2):

I modify my answer to reach out your requirements.

So, if you would like to run a DB constraint try this one :

```
import psycopg2
def your_validator():
    conn = psycopg2.connect("dbname=YOURDB user=YOURUSER")
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    query_result = cursor.execute("YOUR QUERY")
    if query_result is Null:
        # Do stuff
    else:
        # Other Stuff
```

Then use the `pre_save` signal.

In your `models.py` file add,

```
from django.db.models.signals import pre_save
class Dummy(models.Model):
...
    @staticmethod
    def pre_save(sender, instance, *args, **kwargs)
        # Of course, feel free to parse args in your def.
        your_validator()
```

Comment: Thank you for trying to help. Your solution does validation inside Django. I want validation inside the database.

Comment: You re welcome @guettli. My apologies i didn't read _I know how to use validators in Django._

Comment: @guettli i just modify my answer

Comment: why create a DB connection? My code uses Django and I would like to use the django way to get to a DB connection/cursor. I don't see that you create a db constraint. You execute SQL in the validation routine. For me this is something different.